# Need Help regarding backup css

Tags: php, html, css, backup, data-loss

I need your help.

My website css has been crashed due to suddenly power supply off and next while I saw css, CSS was cleaned totally.
Anyone suggest me How can I get them again?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Retrieve them from your source code control system.

If you don't have one, consider this a lesson in why you should.

Answer (score 1):

Try Google webcache for your website. It has usually the content. You may be able to get it from there. If your site is mysite.com, then type this in Google:

```
cache:www.mysite.com
```

And see the results.

Comment: Not get it any right way... please give me alternative suggestion

Answer (score 0):

CSS Style sheets are usually just files alongside the other content. It's hard to believe the site is there, but they are missing.

Check whether the paths are all in order. Try to physically locate the style sheet files first.